# IE Crash Window with Unhandled exception at 0x5BFB9D8D (CtxRast.dll) in iexplore.exe

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, internet-explorer, dll

can you please some body help us ?
    we are getting IE Crash window when we launch 20 to 25 applications using Visual Studio Solution. we are getting below error when we debug .
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\CtxRast.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\CtxRast.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    D:\SwiftShader\SourceCode\D3D9\Win32\Release\CtxRast.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    C:\Windows\CtxRast.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    C:\Windows\symbols\dll\CtxRast.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    C:\Windows\dll\CtxRast.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEE0FD2C9D (ieframe.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000015C.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
-----------------------------------------------
Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE0FD2C9D (ieframe.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000015C.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: CtxRast.dll from Citrix seams to be the cause.

Comment: how to handle this ..can you please give me any suggestion??

Comment: ask your IT support in your company, they know why you use Citrix